# Testng Listener was not found

Tags: testng

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Listener Test">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.test.listener"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test name = "Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name = "testngSelenium.ListenerTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>

public class ListenerTest {

@Test
public void testSucc(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
@Test
public void testFail(){
    Assert.assertTrue(false,"I am asserting false.");
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testFail")
public void testSkip(){
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
}

    public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult testResult){
        System.out.println(testResult.getName());
    }
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult testResult){
        System.out.println(testResult.getName());
    }
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult testResult){
        System.out.println(testResult.getName());
    }
}
```

Check the simple code.Why I tried to run the test suits, the console pops out error Listener com.test.listener was not found in project's classpath? How to correct it? If I run the class instead of suits it is ok.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for `"com.test.listener"` but the class is named `TestListener`.

One of this 2 values is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

// Make sure package name is 'test' or write the correct package name ("packageName.listner") of Listener files location.

Answer (score 0):

Please include packagename.classname in testng suite then it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your classname starts with small letter, why? and please try to use below screenshot to check if you have correctly set your classname and package name and also check your listener class as well

[image: Image1]

Check the Listener class and verify if you have correctly declared your path and method name is set [image: Image2]